# How can you make custom direct3D11 calls in Unreal Engine 4?

Tags: directx11, unreal-4

I have some custom code that renders to Direct3D11 texture.  Is it possible to use this texture on an object in unreal 4?  Or alternatively, is it possible to draw custom geometry directly to the scene in unreal 4 using raw Direct3d?

So far, it seems like I need to make a custom instance of `UPrimitiveComponent` which creates and returns an `FPrimitiveSceneProxy`.  In the `FPrimitiveSceneProxy::CreateRenderThreadResources` I can call `RHIGetNativeDevice` and cast its return to `ID3D11Device` and use it to create Direct3D instances, however, I'm not sure where to put my per-frame draw calls.

Comment: Did you read this post?  https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/255780/how-can-i-get-the-directx-render-device.html

Comment: I have read that.  I'm stuck at "Hard part is to synchronize rendering from the GUI framework with engine:)".

Answer (score 3):

I figured out a way to render to texture.

1. Create a new c++ component that has a `UTextureRenderTarget*` property
2. Create a render target in unreal.  I followed the steps in this short [tutorial](https://youtu.be/jWRkM-95k2I) create a render target, but instead of assigning it to the screen capture camera, I assigned it to the component I made in step 1.
3. Call `ENQUEUE_UNIQUE_RENDER_COMMAND_ONEPARAMETER` from `TickComponent` (or some other game thread function).  In my case, my queued code just calls a `Render` method on a class that has a pointer to the `UTextureRenderTarget` named `renderTarget`.
4. In my `Render` method, I can access the `ID3D11Texture2D` as follows:

   `FTextureRenderTarget2DResource* rtRes = static_cast<FTextureRenderTarget2DResource*>(renderTarget->Resource);
       ID3D11Texture2D* d3dTexture = static_cast<ID3D11Texture2D*>(rtRes->GetTextureRHI()->GetNativeResource());`

Then you can create an `ID3D11RenderTargetView` that maps to the `ID3D11Texture2D` and render. In my case, I got it working by using the `DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_FLOAT` and also setting my render target to the equivalent setting in unreal.